# JSON to table, rows are repeated twice

Tags: reactjs

I have an json which is need to display in a table format, and while displaying the rows are repeated twice.

code to table

```
{row?.map((x, i) => {
      return (
        <tbody>
          {x.amountForQuantity?.map((cost) => {
            return x.budgetedCost?.map((budget) => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <th>{cost.key}</th>
                  <td>{cost.value}</td>
                  <th>{Object.values(budget)[0]}</th>
                </tr>
              );
            });
          })}
        </tbody>
      );
    })}
```

Here is the sandbox - [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-chandrasekhar-gg5iy?file=/src/App.js:826-1322)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each mapped `cost` object you return a table row for each `budget` object.

```
{row?.map((x, i) => {
    return (
        <tbody>
          {x.amountForQuantity?.map((cost) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <th>{cost.key}</th>
                <td>{cost.value}</td>
                <th>
                  {
                    x.budgetedCost.filter((budgetCost) => {
                      return budgetCost.hasOwnProperty(cost.key);
                    })[0][cost.key]
                  }
                </th>
                {/* <th>{Object.values(budget)[0]}</th> */}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
    );
  })}
```

I would recommend if it is possible to change the format of the objects inside the `budgetedCost` array to be the same as the amountForQuantity (having `name` and `key` attributes. It is a bit nasty working out how to get each value otherwise.

Comment: for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(newFilteredArray[0])) {
        arr.push({ key: key, value: value });
      }

This is how budgeted array is created ? how do i convert ?

Comment: Ok looks like your table headings are around the wrong way. `'Budgeted Cost'` is showing `amountForQuantity` and vice versa. That code there looks like it is for `amountForQuantity` which is fine

Comment: update the link and changed the budgetedCost to same as amountForQuantity - https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-chandrasekhar-gg5iy?file=/src/App.js but not able to see the values inside of it

Comment: Is that still the case or did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: i have figured it out, but form on submit the input values are not updated, what am i making wrong ?